# UIStackView Sub StackViews with Different widths and different heights

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, uistackview

Hi I am new to `UISTackView` concept , I know **iOS 9** is still in beta. 
I have a `UIStackView` fills entire screen, stackview contains a number of sub `UISTackViews` `(Nested UIStack views)` , that sub `UIStackViews` having different heights , widths , different sizes , different centers , different margins it's just like random .

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve, so if you could clarify your question that would be helpful.

In interface builder, you can simple hold command and select all the items you want to add to a stack view and then click the stack button at the bottom right of the screen.  (It's the left most of the three, and looks like a stack).

Then if you add other elements, you can command select everything, including another stack view and click the stack view button again.  This will put everything within an even larger stack view.  You can continue doing this over and over.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks , Rob Norback , I solved my self above issue , Any how thanks for your responds